# Room @Insert does not insert all records

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am running into an issue where only 1 record is being inserted into my Room SQLite DB.

When I perform a `getAll();` the result only returns 1 record.

FOUND ISSUE: `Genre[] genres = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Genre[].class);`

This line above is setting all "gid" values to 0, and I am not sure how to change that.

**Genre.java**

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"id", "name"}, unique = true)})
public class Genre {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int gid;

    //@ColumnInfo(name = "id") By Default - No need to annotate
    @NonNull
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getGid() {
        return gid;
    }

    public void setGid(int gid) {
        this.gid = gid;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**GenreDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface GenreDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Genre")
    LiveData<List<Genre>> getAll();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) //If there is a conflict, replace the record.
    void insertAll(Genre... genres);
}
```

**GenreRepository.java**

```
public class GenreRepository {

    private final GenreDao genreDao;

    public GenreRepository(GenreDao genreDao) {
        this.genreDao = genreDao;
    }

    //Database Methods
    public void insertAll(Genre... genres) {
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> { //Same as new Runnable()
            genreDao.insertAll(genres);
        });
    }

    public LiveData<List<Genre>> getAll() {
        return genreDao.getAll();
    }
}
```

**APIUtil.java - getGenres() Method**

This class makes an API call, returns the proper results, converts the JSONArray to a Genre[]. I can successfully loop through the Genre[] and confirm 10+ results come back.

```
public static void getGenres(Context context) {
    APIWrapper wrapper = new APIWrapper(context, API_KEY);

    Parameters params = new Parameters();
    params.addFields(GENRE_FIELDS);
    params.addLimit("50");

    wrapper.genres(params, new onSuccessCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Genre[] genres = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Genre[].class);
            //Insert DB
            AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context);
            GenreRepository genreRepository = new GenreRepository(db.genreDao());
            genreRepository.insertAll(genres);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("GENRES ERROR:", volleyError.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**GenreViewModel.java**

```
public class GenreViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private GenreRepository genreRepository;

    public GenreViewModel(GenreRepository genreRepository) {
        this.genreRepository = genreRepository;
    }

    public void insertAll(Genre... genres){
        genreRepository.insertAll(genres);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Genre>> getAll(){
        return genreRepository.getAll();
    }
}
```

**SearchFragment.java**

This is where I am retrieving the database values. This for loop only returns 1 result.

```
AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getActivity());
GenreRepository genreRepository = new GenreRepository(db.genreDao());
GenreViewModel genreViewModel = new GenreViewModel(genreRepository);
genreViewModel.getAll().observe(this, genres -> { //new Observer<List<Genre>>()
    for(Genre g : genres){
        Log.e("GENRE", g.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you check whethere your genre insert succesfully?i have doubt on that.

Comment: I am not receiving any errors from the insertAll(); how can I verify? I don't believe the insert is working properly because the getAll() only retrieves 1 record.

Comment: you can change the return type of insert to long and get the successfully inserted rows.

Comment: You have `onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`, could it be the cuase? Did you checked that inserted objects are different (or have different id)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insertAll(Genre... genres){
    genreRepository.insertAll(genres);
}
```

here is your mistake  , what you provide as method definition  and what you provide at call. see you make some thing wrong.

Solution

```
 void insertAll(List<T> obj);
```

you can try with convert your array to list and put above in definition

Answer (score -1):

**I had this problem too.**
**And Solved it this way.**

The problem was that the `id` that comes from server was `mongoId` and `String` so I should create a `int primary key` and pass `currentTime` as value to it so the database can **insert** all of them not **replace** them. 
But you should consider using `System.nanoTime()` method instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` cause sometimes it generates same value and then room replace them instead of inserting each one of them.